# spring BeanIsAbstractException

Tags: spring

I'm trying to load spring beans using XmlWebApplicationContext setConfigLocations method.  However, I keep getting a

```
BeanIsAbstractException
```

I know that the bean is abstract, I have it configured this way, so Spring should know not to try to instantiate it.

I'm using Spring2.0.8.jar with jetspeed2.1.

Spring bean:

```
<bean id="ThreadPool" abstract="true" class="com.sample.ThreadPoolFactoryBean"/>
```

Code:

```
ctx = appContext;
    appContext.refresh();
    BeanFactory factory = appContext.getBeanFactory();
    String[] beansName = appContext.getBeanFactory()
            .getBeanDefinitionNames();

...

map.put(beansName[mnCnt], factory.getBean(beansName[mnCnt]));
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you wasting our time by not including all the details immediately ?

Comment: Why are you answering peoples questions with answers and not modifying hte original question.  THis is not a Forum as soon as someone votes for something the order of posts will be altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map.put(beansName[mnCnt], factory.getBean(beansName[mnCnt]));
```

There's your problem, isn't it? By calling getBean with the name of the abstract bean, you try to instantiate it, which will generate an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will try, and fail to create an instance of your abstract class:

```
map.put(beansName[mnCnt], factory.getBean(beansName[mnCnt]));
```

Just so there is no confusion, 'abstract' beans are ***not the same*** as abstract classes.They are primarily a convenient mechanism for reducing duplicate property settings.

> A child bean definition will inherit constructor argument values, 
>       property values and method overrides from the parent, with the option 
>       to add new values. If init method, destroy method, factory bean and/or 
>       factory method are specified, they will override the corresponding 
>       parent settings.

A contrived example:

```
class Fruit {
    private String colour;
    private String name;
    // setters...
}

class Car {
    private String colour;
    private String manufacturer;
    // setters...
}
```

And:

```
<!-- specifying a class for an abstract bean is optional -->
<bean id="sharedPropsBean" abstract="true">
    <property name="colour" value="red" />
</bean>

<bean id="myFruit" parent="sharedPropsBean" class="Fruit">
    <property name="name" value="apple" />
</bean>

<bean id="myCar" parent="sharedPropsBean" class="Car">
    <property name="manufacturer" value="Ferrari" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring bean:

```
<bean id="ThreadPool" abstract="true" class="com.sample.ThreadPoolFactoryBean"/>
```

Code:

```
ctx = appContext;
    appContext.refresh();
    BeanFactory factory = appContext.getBeanFactory();
    String[] beansName = appContext.getBeanFactory()
            .getBeanDefinitionNames();
```

Then when I iterate through the string array it gives the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating and writing the name to say, stdout? That shouldn't cause a problem.
Isn't there anything in your code that tries to force spring to instantiate the bean in question?